# Problem with infinite series of residues

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus, geometric-series

I tried solving the integral
$$ I := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \exp(\mu x)}{\exp(\nu x)-1}\,dx,~~\text{where}~~\text{Re}(\nu)>\text{Re}(\mu) >0$$

using the calculus of residues. I found the  first order poles and calculated the residues
$$ z_n = \frac{2 n \pi i}{\nu},~~n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \lbrace{ 0 \rbrace},~~\text{Res}_{z_n} f = \frac{2 n \pi i}{\nu^2} \exp\left(2 n \pi i \frac{\mu}{\nu} \right).$$
When I now sum over all residues to get the result for the integral I encounter a series
$$ I = \dots = - \frac{4 \pi^2}{\nu^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \exp\left(2 \pi i n \frac{\mu}{\nu} \right) = \dots = \left( \frac{\pi}{\nu} \csc\left( \frac{\pi \mu}{\nu} \right) \right)^2,$$
which I can evaluate by integrating the summands w.r.t $n$, then using the formula for the geometric series and differentiating w.r.t. $n$ again. This gives me the correct result (according to Mathematica). However to use the formula for the geometric series I have to assume that
$$ \left|\exp\left( 2 \pi i  \frac{\mu}{\nu} \right)\right| =\left|\exp\left( -2 \pi \text{Im}\left(\frac{\mu}{\nu} \right)\right)\right|<1$$
and that does not hold for all $\mu,\nu$ fulfilling $\text{Re}(\nu)>\text{Re}(\mu)>0$. Why does this approach give me the correct result although the series appears to diverge for some $\mu,\nu$ and is there some other way to solve this integral by hand?

Comment: Have you analyzed the contour integral $\oint_{|z|=\frac{2\pi }{\nu}(N+1/2)}\frac{ze^{\mu z}}{e^{\nu z}-1}\,dz$?  Is the limit as $N\to \infty$ of this integral equal to $0$?

Comment: I checked the condition $\lim_{|z|\to \infty,\,z \in \mathbb{H}} |zf(z)| = 0$ which should guarantee that the integrale over the semicircle in the upper half plane vanishes. For $\text{Re}(\mu-\nu)<0$ and $z \neq z_n$ I calculated $$ \lim_{|z|\to \infty,\,z \in \mathbb{H}} |zf(z)| = \lim_{|z|\to \infty,\,z \in \mathbb{H}} |z|^2 |e^{(\mu-\nu)z}| |\frac{1}{1-e^{-\nu z}}| = 0$$

Comment: Suppose that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are purely real.  What happens to the integration for values of $z=Re^{i\phi}$ near the imaginary axis?

Comment: Thats where I am unsure. I don't know how to handle that there are infinitely many poles and that I am making my contour infinitely large. Setting $z = i R$ for $R \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\nu,\mu$ purely real I find $$\lim_{|z|\to \infty, z \in \mathbb{H}} |zf(z)| =  \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{R^2}{|1-e^{-i\nu R}|}$$ which is not converging

Answer (score 1):

You could split up the integral into two geometric series

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{\mu x}dx}{e^{\nu x}-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty xe^{(\mu-n\nu)x}dx - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0 xe^{(\mu+n\nu)x}dx$$

$$ = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\mu-n\nu)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\nu^2}\csc^2\left(\frac{\pi\mu}{\nu}\right)$$